# setting values in an array according to set conditions

Tags: arrays

I have an array of value from an image of suns magnetic field. I am meant to set all values above 3*sigma and below -3*sigma to 1. the values in between to 0. and i also have nan values in that array that should stay nan values. i have tried to set several conditions to one array but the conditions overlap if i set them separartely.
is there a way of setting more than one condition at the same time? and how can i do it properly? thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far!

Comment: is this a question about TeX? what language are your "conditions" programmed in?